# How to navigate to a commerce cloud site from an experience cloud log in page

Tags: login, redirect, experience-cloud, commerce-cloud

We're trying to redirect our users to the new commerce cloud page after logging in through the experience cloud log in page but it seems that the in order to properly redirect we need to have something like a buffer page to make sure that the log in carries over, is there a way to remove the buffer and directly jump to the commerce cloud site seamlessly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you quickly redirect from a salesforce site to an sfcc site upon log in](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371172/how-do-you-quickly-redirect-from-a-salesforce-site-to-an-sfcc-site-upon-log-in)

Comment: thanks for accommodating but sadly it doesnt answer my question and i previously posted that but now the circumstances are a bit different